# mobile website format

Tags: .htaccess, mobile, subdomain, cname

I am looking to build a mobile website to my current website and needed some guidance with a few things:

1. Is it possible to put all my mobile files in a folder called mobile then set .htaccess to redirect url with prefix m. to the folder?
2. Is it also possible to hide the a subfolder name from the url so instead of www.website.com/folder/index.php to have m.website.com/index.php?
3. Are there any processor downfalls from using .htaccess excessively?

Much appreciated if anyone can explain these pointers.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes it is possible - you would match the %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} against mobile browsers and redirect them to m.website.com .
2. Yes it's possible to hide a folder - just rewrite it and add the folder name
3. Not really, at least not for these two rules. There may be a slowdown if you have dozens and dozens of rules.

To hide the folder, you could use something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.website\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ folder/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks, have you got a sample code for hiding the folder to show m.website.php for files int he folder?

Comment: Hi, i'm testing this on my local MAMP with structure http://localhost:8888/testsite/mobile/index.php but i cant seem to get it to redirect to http://localhost:8888/testsite/m.index.php

Comment: Well, how are you trying to redirect?

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/edrobein/mobile/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mobile/m.index.php [L,QSA] but the mobile folder is being displayed in the url. I was hopign this would hide the mobile folder

Comment: I can't tell from your rule what you're trying to do - can you explan clearly what you want to show in the URL and what you actually want to serve?

Comment: My error this seems to work                                  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/testsite/m\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mobile/$1 [L,QSA]                                      but it seems to not load css and javascript files